# Google sheets API: Service account authentication: Updating cell value fails with a 403 response, only reading is successful

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, service-accounts

```
from apiclient import discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
  os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'app3-c1824-91dfa420b4a8.json'), 
  scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
)
apiService = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

values = apiService.spreadsheets().values().get(
  spreadsheetId='1fV0fLiLidUEfOQsmZuytRPW6FapkYkFN-NOiZOftLok',
  range='A1'
).execute()

print(f"READ response: {values}") # READ is successful

res = apiService.spreadsheets().values().update(
  spreadsheetId='1fV0fLiLidUEfOQsmZuytRPW6FapkYkFN-NOiZOftLok',
  range='Sheet1!A2',
  valueInputOption='RAW',
  body={
    'values': [['test']]
  }
)

print(f"UPDATE response: {res}") # UPDATE fails with 403
```

Log output for the READ request:

```
2023-09-28 17:45:28 [googleapiclient.discovery_cache] INFO: file_cache is only supported with oauth2client<4.0.0
2023-09-28 17:45:28 [googleapiclient.discovery_cache] INFO: file_cache is only supported with oauth2client<4.0.0
2023-09-28 17:45:28 [googleapiclient.discovery] DEBUG: URL being requested: GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1fV0fLiLidUEfOQsmZuytRPW6FapkYkFN-NOiZOftLok/values/A1?alt=json
2023-09-28 17:45:28 [google_auth_httplib2] DEBUG: Making request: POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
READ response: {'range': 'Sheet1!A1', 'majorDimension': 'ROWS', 'values': [['prashan']]}
```

Log output for the UPDATE request:

```
2023-09-28 17:45:28 [googleapiclient.discovery] DEBUG: URL being requested: PUT https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1fV0fLiLidUEfOQsmZuytRPW6FapkYkFN-NOiZOftLok/values/Sheet1%21A2?valueInputOption=RAW&alt=json
        UPDATE response: <googleapiclient.http.HttpRequest object at 0x106c1ef50>
```

When I open up the returned `res` object from the UPDATE request:

```
res
<googleapiclient.http.HttpRequest object at 0x106c1ef50>
special variables:
function variables:
body: '{"values": [["test"]]}'
body_size: 22
headers: {'accept': 'application/json', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'user-agent': '(gzip)', 'x-goog-api-client': 'gdcl/2.96.0 gl-python/3.11.3', 'content-type': 'application/json'}
http: <google_auth_httplib2.AuthorizedHttp object at 0x108628590>
method: 'PUT'
methodId: 'sheets.spreadsheets.values.update'
response_callbacks: []
resumable: None
resumable_progress: 0
resumable_uri: None
uri: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1fV0fLiLidUEfOQsmZuytRPW6FapkYkFN-NOiZOftLok/values/Sheet1%21A2?valueInputOption=RAW&alt=json'
_in_error_state: False
_process_response: <bound method HttpRequest._process_response of <googleapiclient.http.HttpRequest object at 0x106c1ef50>>
_rand: <built-in method random of Random object at 0x14e0a9c20>
_sleep: <built-in function sleep>
```

When I visit the `res.uri`, I get the following JSON:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

I have properly enabled the Sheets API for the app3 project in which the service account resides:

[image]

The service account has been given "Editor" access to the sheet in question:

[image]

One thing that's interesting is that the UPDATE request doesn't explicitly fail, the log output from the UPDATE request is neutral at best and the `A2` value of the Google sheet remains blank. I have to open up the `res` object to even get to the special json resource that shows me the 403 error. It's complaining about a missing API key, but I am using service account authentication. (Google sheets API does not support WRITE operations using API key authentication anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
res = apiService.spreadsheets().values().update(
  spreadsheetId='1fV0fLiLidUEfOQsmZuytRPW6FapkYkFN-NOiZOftLok',
  range='Sheet1!A2',
  valueInputOption='RAW',
  body={
    'values': [['test']]
  }
)
```

#### To:

```
res = apiService.spreadsheets().values().update(
    spreadsheetId='1fV0fLiLidUEfOQsmZuytRPW6FapkYkFN-NOiZOftLok',
    range='Sheet1!A2',
    valueInputOption='RAW',
    body={
        'values': [['test']]
    }
).execute()
```

- In this modification `.execute()` is added. If you have the write permission of this Spreadsheet, I think that the client of `apiService` can be used for this request.

Comment: Can't believe how much time I spent pulling my hair over this obviously simple mistake

Comment: @PrashanD Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.